# controlling PDF inside safari using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, safari, plugins

Please help about controlling PDFs through JavaScript loaded inside Safari.

Safari uses a PDF plugin of its own something exclusive to Safari and not present in other webkit based browsers like Chrome.

Any of the  or js commands that would work with the Adobe's plugin don't seem to work.

Any help / pointers would be appreciated.

-neeks

http://www.newagelingo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Safari doesn't expose any kind of JS api for extended file types.
Safe to mark it as closed.